# How to save an array when app gets kill

Tags: arrays, swift, persistence, xcode7

I have an array of objects in my app. I use this array to display the properties of the object in an UICollectionView. When I close/kill the app this array gets reset, which is normal. So my question is how to save the array on the device's memory when the app get close and get the array again when open the app again - Thank you.

Array of Message objects:

```
static var MessageArr = Array<Message>()
```

Message class

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Message: NSObject {
    let name : String
    let number : String
    let email: String
    let localDate: String
    let localityPostal: String
    let administrativeArea: String
    let country: String
    let streetName: String
    let mapImage: UIImage



    init(Name : String, Number : String, Email: String = "Ingen E-mail", LocalDate: String, LocalityPostal: String, AdministrativeArea: String, Country: String, StreetName: String, MapImage: UIImage) {

        self.name = Name
        self.number = Number
        self.email = Email
        self.localDate = LocalDate
        self.localityPostal = LocalityPostal
        self.administrativeArea = AdministrativeArea
        self.country = Country
        self.streetName = StreetName
        self.mapImage = MapImage

    }
}
```

Comment: Make your class conform to `NSCoding`, then in `applicationWillResignActive`, archive it to your local data folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/32420488/2303865

Comment: just save it to the ApplicationSupportDirectory folder instead of the caches folder

Comment: You will also need to save your image as data

Comment: BTW it is Swift convention to name its vars starting with a lowercase letter.  init(name : String, number : String, ... and  self.name = name; 
        self.number = number

Comment: What's the problem with the answer given below? Saving it to disk, Core Data or NSUserDefaults are all valid approaches. Either way you still need to define a cleanup mechanism for zombie message arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` or `Core Data`. `NSCache` will get killed if you shut down your app.

Comment: Upvoted. @LeoDabus approach in OP comments valid as well

Comment: @ray - you are not giving @Loc Dai Le enough information. Simply saying `NSUserDefaults` or `Core Data` is not very helpful. Please provide some information on when and how to use these tools.

Comment: @penatheboss I certainly did give him enough information to go and figure it out by himself. SO is not a place to ask people to teach you stuff. SO is a place to come to when you're genuinely stuck and have exhausted your options. And this is good as it enforces good habits.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with you that he should do some research on his own. But it wouldn't hurt to explain a little bit about `NSUserDefaults` or give him a link. Or would it?

Comment: @penatheboss I showed him the tricycle. Not gonna hold his hand while he's on it. Google is our friend.

Comment: But what is he going to do with the tricycle? He's only going to sit there until he learns to ride it. I'm just saying that giving him a small start couldn't hurt

Comment: @penatheboss What you're saying doesn't hold water. Not even a drop lol

Comment: Sorry @ray. I don't have time to waste to argue with you