# Swift: Cannot convert value of type '[String : DayData]' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'

Tags: swift

I'm having trouble saving to CoreData when trying to save a new struct I created.

```
var allInformationByDate = [
"2016-08-13": DayData(sales: 0, doorsKnocked: 0, milesWalked: 0.00, hoursWorked: 0.00)

]

struct DayData { 
let sales: Int
let doorsKnocked: Int
let milesWalked: Double
let hoursWorked: Double
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : DayData]' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'

on this chunk of code, specifically on "allInformationByDate"...

```
var allInfoByDateDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    allInfoByDateDefault.setValue(allInformationByDate, forKey:"allInfoByDateRecord")
    allInfoByDateDefault.synchronize()
```

Does anybody know how to fix this syntax? I've tried changing to

```
allInformationByDate as! AnyObject
```

but that just makes the app crash.

Comment: you need to use a class NSCoding compliant instead of a struct and use NSKeyedArchiver to convert your object to NSData to save it to NSUserDefaults or to a plist file

Comment: In addition to the above, you should be calling `setObject:forKey:` instead of `setValue:forKey:`.  (AnyObject is the "the protocol to which all classes implicitly conform" -- value types such as structs are not classes.)

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't understand a word you just said. But it seems legit...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32420488/2303865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot save custom objects in `NSUserDefaults`

But since all properties of `DayData` are property list compliant you could write an extension of `NSUserDefaults` to convert `DayData` to a dictionary and vice versa.

This extension can write a single `DayData` object as well as a dictionary `[String:DayData]`.

```
extension NSUserDefaults {

 // read a write a single 'DayData' object

  func dayDataForKey(key: String) -> DayData? {
    guard let data = self.objectForKey(key) as? [String:AnyObject] else { return nil }
    return DayData(sales: data["sales"] as! Int, doorsKnocked: data["doorsKnocked"] as! Int, milesWalked: data["milesWalked"] as! Double, hoursWorked: data["hoursWorked"] as! Double)
  }

  func setDayData(dayData : DayData, forKey key: String) {
    let propertyListRepresentation  = ["sales": dayData.sales, "doorsKnocked" : dayData.doorsKnocked, "milesWalked": dayData.milesWalked, "hoursWorked": dayData.hoursWorked]
    self.setObject(propertyListRepresentation, forKey: key)
  }

  // read a write a dictionary ('[String:DayData]') object

  func dayDataDictionaryForKey(key: String) -> [String: DayData]? {
    guard let dayData = self.objectForKey(key) as? [String : [String: AnyObject]] else { return nil }
    var result = [String: DayData]()
    for (key, value) in dayData {
      result[key] = DayData(sales: value["sales"] as! Int, doorsKnocked: value["doorsKnocked"] as! Int, milesWalked: value["milesWalked"] as! Double, hoursWorked: value["hoursWorked"] as! Double)
    }
    return result
  }

  func setDayDataDictionary(dayData : [String: DayData], forKey key: String) {
    var result = [String : [String: AnyObject]]()
    for (key, value) in dayData {
      result[key] = ["sales": value.sales, "doorsKnocked" : value.doorsKnocked, "milesWalked": value.milesWalked, "hoursWorked": value.hoursWorked]
    }
    self.setObject(result, forKey: key)
  }
}
```

Now you can easily write a dictionary to user defaults:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setDayDataDictionary(allInformationByDate, forKey: "allInfoByDateRecord")
```

or read it

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let infoByDateDefault = defaults.dayDataDictionaryForKey("allInfoByDateRecord") {
   allInformationByDate = infoByDateDefault
}
```

Comment: I'm still a noob when it comes to Swift. Where should I put these elements? Thanks!

Comment: Put the extension somewhere on the top level of a file (**not** in a class or struct). Then you can access it from everywhere.

Comment: When I replace my original line with "NSUserDefaults.stand..." it is still giving me an error of "Cannot convert value of type '[String : DayData]' to expected argument type 'DayData'." Any suggestions?

Comment: You are saving a dictionary `[String : DayData]` to user defaults. I updated the answer to consider also this type.

Comment: I'm still getting a BAD_EXC error when I launch the app. It's on this chunk of code in the viewDidLoad: 

    var allInfoByDateDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if (allInfoByDateDefault.valueForKey("allInfoByDateRecord") != nil) {
            allInformationByDate = (allInfoByDateDefault.valueForKey("allInfoByDateRecord") as? [String: DayData])!
        }

The problem is with the last part. But I'm not sure how to change the syntax.

Comment: **Stop writing valueForKey:, the method is completely wrong for this purpose**. The code above extends `NSUserDefaults` with the methods `dayDataForKey` and `dayDataDictionaryForKey` to get a single `DayData` object or a dictionary. I updated the answer how to read from user defaults. Learn to understand how NSUserDefaults works. One again, `valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:` is **wrong**.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `setValue` method. To set a dictionary, call the `setObject` method.

Documentation:

> Sets the value of the specified default key in the standard application domain.
>
> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects...

Also, it's *very* inconvenient to use Swift structs with Objective-C APIs. You need to make your struct conform to `NSCoding` and convert it to `NSData` before storing it to NSUserDefaults. It's basically a whole lot of mess.

You can search for tutorials that show you how to conform to `NSCoding`, but I don't really recommend using it.

`NSUserDefaults` is usually used to save simple data structures, like integers, floats, bools. This is because, after all, it is designed for you to save user preferences and related stuff.

Seeing you have a struct like this, I recommend you to use Core Data instead of `NSUserDefaults`. You can create a data model and generate an `NSManagedObject` subclass based on the struct:

```
class DayData: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var sales: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var doorsKnocked: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var milesWalked: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var hoursWorked: NSNumber?
}
```

Trust me, Core Data is much more convenient in these kinds of circumstances.

For details, take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial).